# There has been a school. What does this sentence mean?

Tags: interpretation

> There has been a school.

Someone says there is still a school.

Someone says there is not a school anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about this sentence.

There has been a school here for a number of years, or there is a school here now.

If there used to be a school here, it is no longer there.